# should I use different Dockerrun.aws.json files for aws eb or set Enviroment variables via eb console

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

let say I have several ElasticBeanstalk enviroments:

- productionMyApp
- stagingMyApp
- qaMyApp

Each environment has really similar Dockerrun.aws.json (what volumes should be linked where) but different environment variables (e.g. what is the RDS db url, what is the Password for RDS, mandril API key ...)

should I store the environment variables for each environment in own file (qa-Dockerrun.aws.json, prod-Dockerrun.aws.json, ...) and tell `eb deploy` to use that file (if so how can I do this ?? )

or

should I set the environments with `eb setenv POSTGRES_PASS=xyzsecretabc` [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html) and **not** place them to Dockerrun.aws.json

Any other suggestions are welcome

I want to avoid having my sensitive information stored in `git` of course

Thank you

Comment: this is kinda helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211007/how-do-you-pass-custom-environment-variable-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-aws-ebs  yet I still want to know is the recommended way

Comment: `.ebextensions` is also a solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/14491294/473040 but in the end the answer shifts to recommending the "set enviroment variables via `Configuration > Software Configuration > Environment Properties`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time I've decided for this solution:

do both :)

It's hard to keep track of all environment variables in elastic beanstalk (and apparently there is a limit number, didn't check that doh) and it's stupid to commit your database passwords to version control.

keep stuff that is already public like `DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR` (RDS public DNS), `DB_ENV_POSTGRES_USERNAME` (postgres username), `REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR`, `S3_BUCKET_NAME`(asset storage bucket) in `Dockerrun.aws.json` and under version control (git)

but stuff like `DB_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, `SECRET_KEY_BASE`, `MANDRIL_API_TOKEN`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as Elastic Beanstalk environments